# My custom view is not visible when embedded inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, custom-view

I know a lot of people have had similar issues to this but I cannot find a solution. I have created a custom View which extends SurfaceView. This view works perfectly when I use :

```
setContentView(graphView);
```

However I want it to be embedded inside a HorizontalScrollView. If I try this with xml with:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<com.stuff.graph.GraphView
android:id="@+id/graph"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then I get a fatal exception and my application closes.

If I try to solve this programatically with:

```
graphView = new GraphView(this);
graphView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

graphView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
myScrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));        

myScrollView.addView(graphView);      

setContentView(myScrollView);
```

Then the screen is just black. I've also tried many variations on the code shown above but none have been successful. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what does your GraphView extends..

Comment: It extends SurfaceView, implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't really the way to solve this issue:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg45804.html

My solution is that I'm not going to use SurfaceView, instead I'm probably going to draw to a Bitmap and put that in an imageview which I can then put inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it in xml no problem - try embedding your custom graph view inside a ListView inside the scroll view; in my experience with horizontalScrollView they tend to be very pick about their contents.  If that doesn't work, try testing to see if there is a problem with the frame view.  Just add a button to the horizontal scroll view and see if you can get that to show up.  If not, then there is a problem trying to display the frame, and it has nothing to do with your custom code.

Comment: I did try this, but if I try to use xml for layout my application just crashes my adb logcat for this is:                                       E/AndroidRuntime( 2900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2900): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stuff.graph/com.stuff.graph.GraphActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.stuff.graph.GraphView

Comment: Ah, ok, that's why you can't inflate the horizontal scroll view, it's just dying more silently on you.  Check your GraphView and see why android would be unable to inflate it.  Also, you know android has its own graphView class that may do something similar, the problem may be as simple as renaming you class or using android's.

Comment: I've fiddled about lots with this xml but nothings working, at this point I'd rather just get it displayed from the Java. Do you have any idea why it may not be displaying correctly?

Comment: You will encounter the same issues getting it to display for java as from xml.  Did you try renaming the class?  Paste your custom layout code on your question; that might help.